# Laravel: Add column contraints

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I have a column named "code" which should accept only 3 character strings, which means it should not take numbers. Any constraints I can apply to the columns?

Comment: What is your database language? MySQL? PostGres? SQL Server? Something else?

Comment: It's my SQL Database

Answer (score 0):

An alternative soultion might be using validation to your case. First, create a column of length three.

> $table->string('name', 3);

Then apply regular expressiong on validation before storing into the database.

> 'name' => 'required|string|max:3|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+$/u'